# Configurations from file for python dictionaries and strings

Tags: python, dictionary, configuration

I have configurations for python script which includes integers, strings and dictionaries. A sample config.txt file is as below

```
mode = 'train,test,validation'

pick_one_in_n_files = 2

#dictionary for labels
labels = dict(
    bowl=0,
    coffee_mug=1,
    food_bad=2,
    food_box=3,
    food_can=4,
    instant_noodles=5,
    plate=6,
    soda_can=7,
    sponge=8,
    water_bottle=9
    )
```

I am reading this text file and writing a new temporary python file with same text as in config. Then import the new python file into my script and use data from it.

```
configuration_import = open(config_path.replace('txt','py'),mode =       'w+')
configuration_text = open(config_path,mode ='r')
configuration_import.write(configuration_text.read())
configuration_import.close()
configuration_text.close()
return importlib.import_module(config_path.replace('.txt',''))
```

This serves the purpose but i am looking for an elegant approach to this problem.

This way the user will only provide a configuration text file. He will not be allowed to edit python files. Drawback is that the file has to be in python format instead of some standard yaml, json etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose just using `with` would clean it up a bit:

```
with open(config_path, mode = 'r') as file_in:
    with open(config_path.replace('.txt', '.py'), mode = 'w') as file_out:
        for line in file_in:
            file_out.write(line)
return importlib.import_module(config_path.replace('.txt',''))
```

Or even just import the file directly without copying it at all.